# I have scaled my images, but how come the screens still aren't the same?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set `anyDensity` to be true in my `manifest.xml` file.

I've scaled my images into ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. They are of course all in their respective folders.

Here are the images of my problem:

[image: Screen 1]

Do I have to make all the different kinds of layouts? For example, `layout-large`, etc etc ?

here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bBaron"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/baron" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDragon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dragon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bBBlue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPBlue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bluecopy" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bBRed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/red" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPRed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/redcopy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimerDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bReset"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
</Button>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
    android:layout_width="466dp"
    android:layout_height="672dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:src="@drawable/summonersrift" />
```

why are all the images not the same size when i've already converted them to all the dpis out there?

For the big picture:

- ldpi: 364 X 387
- mdpi: 486 X 516
- hdpi: 729 X 774
- xhdpi: 972 X 1032
- xxhdpi: 1458 X 1548

Comment: DPI isn't about resolution, but physical size. Many apps need to ensure that buttons and other UI elements have physical size that is convenient to touch on various screen sizes and densities.

Comment: `mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi = 2:3:4:6`. Make sure you image's dimensions are in this ratio. They'll look of same size (in inches) on screen. If the images don't fit, consider making layout scrollable.

Comment: @LieRyan I think DPI relates resolution to physical size: 160dpi means 48 dots take 0.3 inches of space on screen.

Comment: yeah my images' dimensions are absolutely in this ratio. this is why i'm still concerned about this problem. some of the devices still have white space remain at bottom and some have a bunch as you can see from the last picture

Comment: instead of given the height and layout some dp numbers. u should consider using match_parent and wrap_content with layout_below and layout_above.

Comment: If you want your app to do what I call "percent-perfect design", you don't need the DPI mechanism. Just create an image for the largest supported screen resolution and dynamically scale them to 100% device width with wrap_content. Just be aware that percent perfect design might look awkward on devices with different densities, because buttons will be too small for high density phones or too large in tablet.